# How can I use remote host options TCPProxy on Grinder?

Tags: client-server, desktop-application, performance-testing, grinder, remote-host

I want to test Desktop application with Grinder. My application is multiple client/server app. I must use TCPProxy and remotehost options. But I couldn't. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this. if we connect a remote host and if we use proxy, we must set proxy:

Open cmd
cd c:\grinder
C:\grinder>java net.grinder.TCPProxy -remotehost myremotehost -remoteport myremoteport -console>test.py
and recording process